# How to have 2 different results in a bootstrap dropdown separated by a heading?

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript, autocomplete

I am trying to show different results in a single autocomplete result differentiating with the heading. I have 2 roles Subject and Teacher, when searching with some letter I want to show both the results of Teacher and Subject, but want to differentiate as below

Expected Output

[expected output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zaIAK.png)

Teacher heading will differentiate the 2 result sets

The output I am getting

```
Subject
Math
...

Maddy
....
```

The link to the code is [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6l51vd?file=app%2Fapp.component.html)

Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: I can't seem to understand what is your output supposed to be (your output doesn't match what I see in live server). Can you provide a screenshot perhaps?

Comment: @GytisTG I have added the screenshot please check now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Slightly updated logic:

Typescript:

```
export class AppComponent {
  typeahead: FormControl = new FormControl();
  countries = countries;

  suggestions = {
    countries: [],
    teachers: [],
  };

  suggest() {
    this.suggestions = {
      countries: this.countries
        .filter(c => c.role === 'Subject')
        .filter(c => c.name.startsWith(this.typeahead.value))
        .slice(0, 5),
      teachers: this.countries
        .filter(c => c.role === 'Teacher')
        .filter(c => c.name.startsWith(this.typeahead.value))
        .slice(0, 5),
    };
  }
}
```

HTML:

```
<input type="text" [formControl]="typeahead" placeholder="Type ahead !" (input)="suggest()">
<div class="suggestions">
  <ng-container *ngFor="let s of suggestions.countries; let i = index">
    <h3 *ngIf="i === 0">{{ s.role }}</h3>
    <p>{{ s.role }} - {{ s.name }}</p>
  </ng-container>

  <ng-container *ngFor="let s of suggestions.teachers; let i = index">
    <h3 *ngIf="i === 0">{{ s.role }}</h3>
    <p>{{ s.role }} - {{ s.name }}</p>
  </ng-container>
</div>
```

Your example doesn't work because in html only the first element is being checked (when deciding when to put h3 tag) and it was with the role `Teacher`. Splitting into 2 fields will result in you being able to separately iterate each of them and apply logic (in this case, check if `i === 0`).